# toogle component on click with react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm toggling a component while clicking on div . It toogle down when clicked but does not close when clicked again what am i doing wrong?

```js
export default function Shiva() {
    const [loan, setLoan] = useState(false);
    const handleClick = () => {
        setLoan(true);      
    }
return (
<div className="">
    <div className="">
        <div className="loan-type-select" onClick={handleClick}>
            <div className="">
                <img src="" />
            </div>
            <p>SBA 7A Loan</p>
            {loan ? <Data /> : '' }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Look closely at your click handler:

```
const handleClick = () => {
    setLoan(true);      
}
```

Regardless of the current state of `loan`, it will always set the new state of `loan` to `true`.

If you want to close it when it's open, toggle the current state instead of passing `true`.

```
const handleClick = () => {
    setLoan(!loan);
}
```

Comment: Since react setState is an asynchronous call, it's best to make use of the previous value instead of the state value.
`setLoan(prevLoan => !prevLoan)`

Comment: That technique useful when the state setter could have been called by something *else* before a re-render, but that's not the case here, in which case it just results in more syntax noise for no benefit IMO.

Comment: It seems quite easy but as a begineer seems time consuming to solve it. Thanks! Your reply helped a lot! @CertainPerformance

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add that instead of using:

```
setLoan(!loan)
```

It is better to use:

```
setLoan((preValue)=>{!preValue})
```

This way you make sure you won't face any issues (you are changing the previous value instead of changing the actual value).